# Python API : Which alternative to 'collection.objects.link' for many objects?

Tags: python, performance

I have generated objects to add in a `collection` using a python script.

When adding about 3500 objects, I have performance issues : it takes about 0.5 second to run the following python loop.

```py
    collection = bpy.data.collections.new('arrDynamic')

    for obj in allObjs:
        collection.objects.link(obj)

    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(collection)
```

I could not find an API that would allow me to add multiple objects at once.

Is there any simple way I could use to improve the performance for adding many objects in a collection ?

**Edit** I initially had much larger performance issues, which were caused by objects using materials referencing image files with incorrect paths.

Comment: That's pretty much instantaneous for me. Maybe give a self-contained example (that shows allObjs getting created).

Comment: @scurest Thanks for taking the time to look, I tried to repro from an empty script - I rephrased my question as my huge time values were caused by an another issue (missing images in materials) :}

Comment: Re edit a classic case of [XY Problem wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) or on meta   [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Had a doozy once where I failed to see a comma for a period. Re performance  May get a squeak more using a generator. Will depend on  creation of the objects / data.  Have never tried timing it, did notice that _eg_ `obs = (bpy.data.objects.new(f"Foo{n}", mesh) for i in range(n))` (surprisingly appeared  to outperform `ob.copy()` )   Perhaps [edit] in a runnable test case scenario and put up as a challenge.